# dynamiclly build object keys in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of array:

var someArray = ['9213','9234'];

I want to do the following have the following result:

```
var obj = {
   9213:true,
   9234:true
}
```

How can i achieve this? something like:

```
obj = [];
_.each(someArray, function(currentNum,i){
     obj.push(); //here i should do something 
})
```

Comment: If you want an object (`{}`) why are you initialising an array (`[]`)?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
obj = {}; // {} means object and [] means array
_.each(someArray, function(currentNum,i){
     obj[ currentNum ] = true;
     //by using [ currentNum ] you will create object property name as "9213" for example.
})
```